# C++ Writing to array in function

Tags: c++

The problem is that the contents of the array "data" change to these seemingly random numbers when I try to access them in main, after the "ReadFile" function has run. The numbers are the same for the same input.
I think it has something to do with pointers or references, but I dont what it is.

Examples:

INPUT:

> 4000
>
> -2500
>
> 12
>
> -600
>
> -700
>
> 3000

OUTPUT:

> Number of lines: 6
>
> 2686316
>
> 4706252
>
> 1
>
> 1991562344
>
> 4661696
>
> 4703488

CODE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
const int MAXN = 100;

string ReadFileName(string& filename) {
    cout << "The name of the file: ";
    cin >> filename;
    return filename;
}

int ReadFileLength(int& linecount, string filename) {
    ifstream f;
    bool error;
    do {
        ReadFileName(filename);
        f.open(filename.c_str());
        error=f.fail();
        if(error) {
            cout << "Error while tying to open file." << endl;
            f.clear();
        }
    }
    while (error);

    int tmp;
    while (f >> tmp) {
        linecount++;
    }
    f.close();
    return linecount;
}

void ReadFile(int* data, int linecount, string filename) {
    ifstream f;
    f.open(filename);
    for(int i=0; i<linecount; i++)
        f >> data[i];
    f.close();
}

int main() {
    int data[MAXN];
    bool error;
    int readmethod;
    int linecount = 0;
    string filename;

    do {
        message1();
        cin >> readmethod;
        error = cin.fail() || ((readmethod!=1) && (readmethod!=2));
        if (error) {
            cout << "Wrong Data!" << endl;
            cin.clear(); string tmp; getline(cin, tmp, '\n');
       }
    }
    while(error);

    if (readmethod==1) {
        ReadFileLength(linecount, filename);
        ReadFile(data, linecount, filename);
    }
    else {
        //Implement later
    }

    cout << "Number of lines: " << linecount << endl;

    for (int i=0; i<linecount; i++) {
        cout << data[i] << endl; //THIS IS WHERE TO PROBLEM SHOWS UP
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have omitted "message1" and "ReadFileLength" functions from the code because they are working fine.

Comment: Did the file open correctly?

Comment: What happens if the file isn't read in?  Or the file isn't there?  You need to test for error cases, this may tell you if the file opened or not.  So I'd surround it with a try/catch block or at least check that the stream into is null or not.  hope that helps

Comment: And for your test-case, `readmethod` is `1`?

Comment: Yes it did. The number of lines for example is always correct, the problem is with the array.

Comment: Yes, readmethod is 1.

Comment: Initialise your array so you can tell whether it was actually written to, `int data[MAXN] = {0};`.

Comment: To start with, you need to actually check for errors when reading, and also make sure the file is actually opened. Then if there are no errors or other problems reading the file, then you should use a debugger to step though the code, line by line, to make sure that it works as you expect.

Comment: After initializing, it seems that the function does not actually write to the array. (It returns 0s after I initialized it like you said.)

Comment: The file name is tested in the "ReadFileLength" function, but I omitted that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My crystal ball says:

Your `ReadFileLength` not only calculates the length, but also asks for a filename.
Unfortunately  you forgot to pass that parameter as a reference (`std::string& filename`), or forgot to assign to the parameter.
Thus, the filename is still the empty string when the function returns, and opening a file with that name is bound to fail.

BTW, asking for a filename and retrieving the length of a file sounds like two unrelated functions that both return a single value, not one function.

Comment: @piedpiper Just molbdnilo said, you read the file name in `ReadFileLength` (through the `ReadFileName` function) but the `filename` argument is pass by value. When posting questions with coe, please try to make a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us, so we don't have to guess.

Comment: I edited the question to include the passing and checking of the filename with the functions "ReadFileLength" and "ReadFileName".

Comment: Print the value of "filename" just before the "f.open" lines and you'll see what he means.

Comment: After printing the filename, it seems to be there in "ReadFileLength but not in "ReadFile".
Does this mean that the "ReadFileName" function only passes the filename to "ReadFileLength" but not to main?

Comment: Okay, thanks I solved it now by simply adding an ampersand after "string" in this line:
    `int ReadFileLength(int& linecount, string& filename) {`

I thought that the filename in ReadFileName would be passed to the main function, but I was wrong. Thanks again.